# R Different years on axes for scatter in panel

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to receive your help. I am struggling (not so much familiar with R and further motivation to study it more)
I have a panel (countries) and 1 variable (field_mismatch) available only for 2 years (2015-2016). I would like to have a scatterplot with on the x-axis the year 2015 while, on the y-axis the year 2016.
Within it, the values that those countries have and a 45 degree line. I would like to have a different color for EU28 and LVA.
Can someone help me in what kind of code should I write?
Thank you very much

[image: short data sample]

Comment: You have to do some data wrangling. See [Scatter plot with ggplot, using indexing to plot subsets of the same variable on x and y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70171815/scatter-plot-with-ggplot-using-indexing-to-plot-subsets-of-the-same-variable-on/70172623#70172623) for an example which should fit your use case.

Comment: Thank you, stefan. The link was useful and I have managed to have the scatter. However, I still miss to have it as I would like. Might I ask a further help?  How do I know which country is "EU28" and "LVA" once I use "mutate(country = row_number()"? And have them with different colours? Thank you again.

Comment: Hi sicecon. My fault. Your `country` column is already the id column, i.e. remove `group_by(Year) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% ungroup()`. As for the colors you could add `mutate(country_lump = if_else(country %in% c("LVA", "EU28"), country, "Other"))` and do `ggplot(..., aes(... color = country_lump))`.

Comment: No problem. Thank you once more. Unfortunately, the "mutate" code gives me back an error message saying "object country not found". I see my data and the column "country" is there. Nothing is plotted now:(